# MySQL- How to store data accessed from MySQL through select statement into a string?

Tags: java, mysql, jsp, jdbc

I have a table in MySQL that has user credentials (username, password) and  first name, last name.

I passed the username from my `Login.java` page through cookies to my `welcome.jsp` page. What I want to do is: Run a `SELECT` statement in my table to retrieve the user's first name using the `username` they used to log in. Like this:

```
SELECT `first_name` FROM table WHERE username = userName;
```

`userName` is the variable for the username the user used to log in to my application. This select statement should return the first name of the user.

My Question is: how do I store this into a string?

Comment: learn jdbc properly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
try{  
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");  
Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection(  
"jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/sonoo","root","root");  
//here sonoo is database name, root is username and password  
Statement stmt=con.createStatement();  
ResultSet rs=stmt.executeQuery("SELECT first_name FROM table WHERE username = '"+ userName+"';");
String fname;  
while(rs.next())  
fname=new String(rs.getString(1));
System.out.println("First Name:"+fname);  
con.close();  
}
catch(Exception e){ 
  System.out.println(e);
 }
```

Comment: Thank You! This was helpful

Comment: I actually have a question- When I tried this out, what happened was it returned the first input I had in my table, not the first Name of the user associated with the username I had passed in. Is it because of the rs.getString(1)?

Comment: no its not because of rs.getString(1). you have teamviewer?

Comment: Im sorry, I'm still new to this- i dont know what team viewer is..